# Showing the attribute from another table in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I have two tables Shift and ShiftSession. The relationship is like shift have many shiftsessions and shiftsession belongs to shift.

I define the relationship on the model of shiftsession like this.

```
var $name = 'ShiftSession';                    
var $belongsTo = array(        
      'Shift' => array(            
         'className'    => 'Shift',            
         'foreignKey'    => 'ShiftID'
       )    
    );
```

The question is that I want to show the name of the shift from shift table instead of shiftID in the shiftsession table.

Answer (score 0):

You have to try:

```
$this->ShiftSession->find('all');
```

this will return you corresponding data from `Shift` table.